# how to setup default style and user defined style in react native dynamically?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

In my react native App, i am just trying to add a shared component called **RoundImageComponent**  and added a **RoundImageComponent.style** to add css styles. When use this Round image component, width of the image will be passed as props according to the requirement in the application. In some cases, width will be not added to the component tag as follow,

```
RoundImageComponent width={90} roundImage="https://media.wired.com/photos/593222b926780e6c04d2a195/master/w_2400,c_limit/Zuck-TA-AP_17145748750763.jpg" />
```

or

```
RoundImageComponent roundImage="https://media.wired.com/photos/593222b926780e6c04d2a195/master/w_2400,c_limit/Zuck-TA-AP_17145748750763.jpg" />
```

**RoundImageComponent Code**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
Text,
View,
} from 'react-native';
import Config from 'react-native-config';
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';
import RoundImageComponent from "./shared/avatar/RoundImageComponent";
import styles from './App.styles';

const resolveSession = async () => {
 // const session = sessionActions.getSession();
 SplashScreen.hide();
};

setTimeout(() => {
 resolveSession();
}, 2000);

const App = () => (
<View style={styles.container}>
<RoundImageComponent width={90}roundImage="https://media.wired.com/photos/593222b926780e6c04d2a195/master/w_2400,c_limit/Zuck-TA-AP_17145748750763.jpg" />
</View>
);

export default App;
```

**RoundImageComponent**

```
import {
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';

import { container, primaryText } from '../../theme/base';


export const defaultImage = {
height: 100,
borderRadius: 50,
width: 100
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
 ...container,
},
 userDefinedImage: {
...defaultImage,
width: 40
 }
});

export default styles;
```

When user pass the width as prop, image width should override to the default width and otherwise image width should remain as default width.
Is it possible to do with on this way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is possible by passing props to styles. Suppose this as my `CustomTextComponent`:

```
export CustomTextComponent = (props)=>{
     return (
         <Text style={[{fontFamily:"Lato", color:"#000", ...props.style}]}>
                {props.children}
        </Text>
    )
}
```

Now I want to set different color at different level lets say red and green then

for `red`

```
<CustomTextComponent style={{color:'red'}}> 
           red colored text
</CustomTextComponent>
```

for `green`

```
<CustomTextComponent style={{color:'green'}}> 
           red colored text
</CustomTextComponent>
```

**Note:** Your `...props.style` is should be after your default styling. because your last mentioned will override previous one.
You can also make use of `default props value` in some cases.(lib `PropsType`)

Comment: This "<Image style={[styles.image,this.props.style]}
                source={{ uri: this.props.roundImage }}
            />" worked for me. Thanks

Comment: When use this one "<Text style={[{fontFamily:"Lato", color:"#000", ...props.style}]}>" , it gets error "Can't find variable :props"

Comment: you need to send props of name style from your calling and if statefull component it should be `this.props.style` other wise `props.state` for **presentational component**

Comment: Then, what's the meaning of "...props.style"?

Comment: i think there is a typo,{[{fontFamily:"Lato", color:"#000", ...props.style}]}> should be:  {[{fontFamily:"Lato", color:"#000"}, ...props.style]}>

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible.

You can override the current style prop by passing another one just after it. It would looks something like this:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  default: {
    backgroundColor: red,
    color: blue,
  },
});

<View>
  <DefaultComponent style={styles.default} />
  <CustomComponent style={[styles.default, { backgroundColor: none }]} />
</View>
```

Hope it helps